# django prepopulate modelform - nothing happens

Tags: django, django-forms, instance

This must be a very simple thing however I can not seem to get through it..

I trying to build a form where the user can update a ModelForm. First he inserts a user id and afterwards I want to show him the form pre-populate with the original data so he can change only the fields that he wants.

After some the help of my friend google, stackoverflow and the django documentation, I've come to this:

views.py

```
 user = User.objects.get(user_id=usr)  
 if request.method == 'POST':  
      form = TableForm(request.POST)  
      if form.is_valid():  
           #do something  
 else:  
      form = TableForm(instance=user)  
      return render_to_response('template.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class TableForm(forms.ModelForm):
     pres_clinic = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=PresClinic.objects.all(),
        widget=SelectWithPop(), label=ugettext("Clinic presentation"),
        required=False)

     MAYBECHOICES = (
         ('', '---------'),
         (ugettext('Yes'), ugettext('Yes')),
         (ugettext('No'), ugettext('No')))

     bcg_scar = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MAYBECHOICES, label=ugettext(
            "BCG scar"), required=False)
     mantoux_register = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MAYBECHOICES,
        label=ugettext("Mantoux register"), required=False)
     date_diag = forms.DateField(widget=DateTimeWidget, label=ugettext(
         "Diagnosis date"), required=False)
     situation = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Situation.objects.all(),
        widget=SelectWithPop(), label=ugettext("Patient status"),
        required=False)
     date_situation = forms.DateField(widget=DateTimeWidget, label=ugettext(
        "Date patient status"), required=False)

  class Meta:
    model = Table
    fields = ('pres_clinic', 'bcg_scar', 'mantoux_register',
            'date_diag', 'situation', 'date_situation')

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    diag = cleaned_data.get('date_diag')

    errors = []

    now = datetime.date.today()

    if diag is not None and diag != u'':
        if diag > now:
            errors.append(ugettext('The field "Diagnosis date" should be '
                'smaller than the actual date'))
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)

    return cleaned_data
```

template:

```
 {{ form }} # presents the empty form and not the data from that user
```

The version of django is 1.4

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and why I'm not able to see the form populated?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you quickly edit in your form code? As in the tableform code...

Comment: @Jeff I've added the form however I've omitted some lines since it's bigger but the structure is there. Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define a dictionary to be used for the initial data and change from TableForm(instance=user) to TableForm(initial=dict), for example something like:

```
 user = User.objects.get(user_id=usr)  
 if request.method == 'POST':  
     form = TableForm(request.POST)  
     if form.is_valid():  
         #do something  
 else:  
      data = {'pres_clinic' : 'value', 'bcg_scar' : 'value', 'mantoux_register' : 'value'}
      form = TableForm(initial=data)  
 return render_to_response('template.html',{'form':form})
```

I would also put the render to response out of the if statement so if the form isn't valid the page should reload and show any errors.

More information on the [django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I also though about the initial with the dictionary. However I do not understand why the instance doesn't work. For what I've seen it should work and would be better than create a dictionary for each field.. Do you know why the instance does not work? in this situation

Comment: My guess is as you are supplying an instance of a user model to the tableform (which is expecting a tableform model) it fails. That would be my initial assumption though and may not be correct!

Comment: :) guess absolutely right!! I've tried with an instance of tableform. Thank you so such. I've spent hours trying to understand why it wouldn't work.. And it was quite simple :p thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can try 'model_to_dict'

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

 user = User.objects.get(user_id=usr)  
 if request.method == 'POST':  
     form = TableForm(request.POST)  
     if form.is_valid():  
         #do something  
 else:          
     form = TableForm(initial=model_to_dict(user))  
 return render_to_response('template.html',{'form':form})
```